# Unphysical Solution of the Bethe Ansatz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integrable-systems, spin-chains

I actually want to ask an elementary question regarding the algebraic Bethe-Ansatz.

Say I have constructed the Bethe Ansatz Equations (BAE) in the algebraic framework with pseudovacuum $\phi$, $B(u)$ are the standard generators, $\tau(u)$ is the transfermatrix and $H$ is the Hamiltonian, which is contained in the spectral expansion of $\tau$. Then I thought the following implication follows:

$\{v_i\} \text{ solution of BAE} \Longrightarrow B(v_1)....B(v_n)\phi \quad \text{is eigenstate of } \tau(u)$

However, now I came cross some reference regarding the completeness of the Bethe-Ansatz which talk about unphysical solutions of the BAE. So solutions of the BAE, which do not correspond to  energies of $H$. How do they arise if the above implication hold? Or is the above implication just wrong? If yes, where is the loophole?

Comment: One particular case in which a solution can be "unphysical" is when the Bethe vector is a *null vector*, meaning that it has zero norm ( $\langle \boldsymbol \lambda | \boldsymbol \lambda \rangle = 0$)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!